# page.content() is different from what I see in the browser (Using Proxies)

Tags: python, playwright

When using Proxies in Playwright I get a different output in the HTML code from what I see in the browser. Why happens this?

If I don't use the Proxy everything works ***perfectly***.

I could say the page is "detecting" I'm using a proxy, but if that is the case, how I am able to see everything as normal in the browser?

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:

        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False, proxy={
                "server": "",
                "username": "",
                "password": ""
            })

        page = await browser.new_page()

        await page.goto("URL")
        await page.get_by_role("button", name="Search").click()

        # HTML
        print(await page.content())

        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

What is worth mentioning is that this doesn't happen when the page "loads" the first time, but when I start performing actions and there is a new load of the page.

In the browser, I see everything correctly, but I get the HTML output without body tag, for example:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
</html>
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you waiting for the page to load after the click before snapshotting the content?